# ggplot2: how to align grobs to sides using arrangeGrob()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to split the title into two parts that are left/right-aligned respectively. The following code creates two textgrobs and uses `arrangeGrob()` to arrange the plot. But it seems there is no options in `arrangeGrob()` to align grobs. How can I align `grobs1` to the left of the plot and and `grobs2` to the right of the plot? Thanks.

```
    p <- ggplot()

    grobs1 <- grobTree(
      gp = gpar(fontsize = 14), 
      textGrob(label = "Left", name = "title1",
               x = unit(2.5, "lines"), y = unit(0, "lines"), 
               hjust = 0, vjust = 0),
      textGrob(label = " left", name = "title2",
               x = grobWidth("title1") + unit(2.5, "lines"), y = unit(0, "lines"),
               hjust = 0, vjust = 0, gp = gpar(col = "red", fontface = "bold"))
      )

    grobs2 <- grobTree(
      gp = gpar(fontsize = 14), 
      textGrob(label = "Right", name = "title1",
               x = unit(0, "lines"), 
               y = unit(0, "lines"),
               hjust = 0, vjust = 0),
      textGrob(label = " right", name = "title2",
               x = grobWidth("title1") +unit(0, "lines"), 
               y = unit(0, "lines"),
               hjust = 0, vjust = 0, gp = gpar(col = "red", fontface = "bold"))
    )

    gg <- arrangeGrob(p, top = arrangeGrob(grobs1, grobs2, ncol = 2), padding = unit(1, "line"))
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(gg)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two arguments of `textGrob` function could be helpful to move the text horizontally: `just` and `hjust`. You could try to adjust those values to get what you are after. By the way, I assume that you used the `gridExtra` package. I have only made some changes in `just` and `hjust` of your original code. I might have gone too far to push the `right` text to the right with `hjust = -5`, and `just = "right"` could be sufficient.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot()
    grobs1 <- grobTree(
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 14), 
    textGrob(label = "Left", name = "title1",
             x = unit(2.5, "lines"), y = unit(0, "lines"), 
             just = "left", hjust = 0, vjust = 0),
    textGrob(label = " left", name = "title2",
             x = grobWidth("title1") + unit(2.5, "lines"), y = unit(0, "lines"),
             just = "left", hjust = 0, vjust = 0, gp = gpar(col = "red", fontface = "bold"))
  )

  grobs2 <- grobTree(
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 14), 
    textGrob(label = "Right", name = "title1",
             x = unit(0, "lines"), 
             y = unit(0, "lines"),
            just = "right", 
            hjust = -5, 
            vjust = 0),
    textGrob(label = " right", name = "title2",
             x = grobWidth("title1") +unit(0, "lines"), 
             y = unit(0, "lines"),
             just = "right", 
             hjust = -5, 
             vjust = 0, gp = gpar(col = "red", fontface = "bold"))
  )

  gg <- arrangeGrob(p, top = arrangeGrob(grobs1, grobs2, ncol = 2), padding = unit(1, "line"))
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wish there were a cheat sheet for manipulating grobs.